# How to overlap an image and a table in beamer?

Tags: tables, beamer, includegraphics

I'm creating a beamer presentation with the following content:

First I want to present a list of components in form of a table, which works perfectly. But in the following I would like to show a picture of one of these components in front of the table (maybe with the table grayed out, but still visible behind the image). An example is shown in the following picture:

[image: Image in front of table]

How do I implement this in beamer?

Thank you very much for any answer.

Comment: You can use the options `remember picture` and `overlay` of tikz for this. See [PGF manual](http://mirrors.ctan.org/graphics/pgf/base/doc/pgfmanual.pdf) section "17.13 Referencing Nodes Outside the Current Picture" (p. 259 f.).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Without tikz, to overlap the image a negative horizontal space is enough. For the vertical alignment and rotation, you can use `angle` option an `adjustbox` to set `valign`, for example.

[image: mwe]

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usepackage[export]{adjustbox}
\begin{document}
\begin{frame}
\begin{tabular}{llll}
    11 & 12 & 13 & 14\\
    21 & 22 & 23 & 24\\
    31 & 32 & 33 & 34\\
    41 & 42 & 43 & 44\\
\end{tabular}\hspace{-7em}
\visible<2>{\includegraphics[valign=t,width=3.5em,angle=45]{example-image}}
\end{frame}     
\end{document}
```

Comment: Ok, that works. Thank you very much :) !